# Authentication Javascript with Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, spotify

I need to authenticate in Spotify Web Api without dialog text for approved, or load in a  complete page and after load a page with results.

My code:

```
     function login(callback) {
    var CLIENT_ID = 'ID CLIENT';
    var REDIRECT_URI = 'REDIRECT URI';
    function getLoginURL(scopes) {
        return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
          '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
          '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
          '&response_type=token';
    }

    var url = getLoginURL([
        'playlist-modify-public'
    ]);

    var width = 450,
        height = 730,
        left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
        top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
            callback(hash.access_token);
        }
    }, false);

    var w = window.open(url,
                        'Spotify',
                        'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
                       );
}
```